# Mathematical Notion of Writing Recursive Algorithms Iteratively

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, recursive-algorithms

So this is a part computer science, part math question, but as I am more curious about this from a mathematical perspective. I know from Comp. Sci. classes the following theorem (roughly);

Theorem: Any algorithm that can written recursively can also be written iteratively, possibly needing the assistance of a supplementary data structure.

While this makes sense, I was wondering how a mathematician might prove this? How do we state this as a problem in pure math, and how would one go about proving the statement?

Comment: Well, first one needs a mathematical formalization of "algorithm", "iteratively", and "data structure". I don't think the following is exactly what you wanted, but: Turing machines are a model of computation that can be said to be purely iterative (being a state machine) with a data structure (the tape), while lambda calculus is in a sense purely recursive; Turing showed the two are equivalent in an appendix to his seminal 1936 paper.

Comment: I don't really know lambda calculus but this seems right. I think algorithm should be defined the way Turing would define it, iteratively would be to say that the algorithm is not self-referential, and data structure would mean roughly that "we have the ability to know the state of the algorithm at any point in the past" (so that, say, if we are traversing a graph, we know what path we took to get where we are now).